# How to trigger Jenkins job based on file type

Tags: jenkins

Currently, below is how the Jenkins jobs are configured for our system

Job1 --> Job2 --> Job3 & Job4

Job1 - This gets triggered once the SVN commit is made.
Job2 - This is triggered by Job1 and SVN revision is inputted to Job2
Job3 & Job 4 --> These are triggered by Job 2 and SVN revision number is inputted to these by Job 2

What I am looking for:

1. I want Job1 to trigger Job2 only if there are C code changes in the SVN commit. If there are "NO" C code changes, it should directly trigger Job 3 and Job 4.
2. If there are C file changes, the existing flow should work as it is.

Answer (score 0):

That should be a task for the [JENKINS Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin)

You can add/script a condition on a step, and if that condition passes, that step can trigger another job (like job2).
If not, the next steps could trgger job3 and 4.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58002645/screen-capture-1.jpg?version=1&modificationDate=1321296168000&api=v2]

The OP shiva  adds in the comments:

> For job2, there are already some conditional steps i.e. based on the inputs it gets from job1, job2 executes different scripts.
>   I want this C file check on top of all the steps. So that, if this check passes, it should execute other conditional steps.

Then you can insert an intermediate job between job1 and job2: it will be just there for your current test. But in job1, your conditional step should be only to test C code changes in the SVN commit. And call that "1.5" intermediate job. Which in turn will call job2.

> How to check from Jenkinsk, if the SVN commit had C files.

Have a look at the [Pipeline utility steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/): once an SVN commit is checked out, you can look for `*.c` files in the work

Comment: for job2, there are already some conditional steps i.e. based on the inputs it gets from job1,  job2 executes different scripts.

I want this C file check on top of all the steps. So that, if this check passes, it should execute other conditional steps

Comment: @shiva Then you can insert an intermediate job between job1 and job2: it will be just there for your current test. But in job1, your conditional step should be only to test C code changes in the SVN commit. And call that "1.5" intermediate job. Which in turn will call job2.

Comment: i will try this approach. How to check from Jenkinsk, if the SVN commit had C files. I tried searching it, but couldn't find the correct answer.